# Default homepage, and search engine changed in all the browsers

Tags: windows-7, malware

Default homepage, and search engine changed in Chrome, IE and Firefox . Every time I make a change in Firefox, when it works till I close the browser. When the browser is started the next time , same site is opened. I want to fix this. I am sure this is some kind of malware, just don't have an idea on how to remove it. I am using Windows 7.

The default site that is getting opened is http://indiasearcher.in/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should uninstall the software that cause this (if possible). Also I would recommend you download and run [Hitman Pro](http://www.surfright.nl/en/downloads/) (it is very good tool to remove viruses and malware). Then you should download and run [Spybot - Search & Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/), this tool can find changed settings in your system and reset them to original values.

Anyway ones the malware is gone, you should be able to change all settings like before.